# Fancypopup does not update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fancybox

I have tried to solve this for several hours with no luck. This is my problem:

When I click a button a fancybox popup will open and show me accounts from mysql. I have a remove button in the same popup that lets me remove a certain account. When I press that remove button the popup with the accounts closes and another popup is opened asking me if I want to remove the account. When I press yes the account is removed from mysql and the popup is closed. Everything works so far but...

When I open the popup with the accounts again the account that I deleted is still there, but not in mysql. It seems that fancybox caches my account or something like that. If I quit everything and open the account popup again the account is deleted and reflect what is in mysql.

I use the following code to open and close popups.

```
$.fancybox.close();

$.fancybox.open('#inline16');
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

```
<div id="inline16" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Are you sure you want to remove the account?></h3> 
    <form id="myform" method="post" action=""> 
    </form> <br> 
    <input type="button" onclick="close_popup()" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="button" onclick="delete_account_2()" value="Yes" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: could you post the content of `#inline16` ?

Comment: <div id="inline16" style="display: none;">
<h3>Are you sure you want to remove the account?></h3>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
</form>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="close_popup()" value="Cancel" /><input type="button" onclick="delete_account_2()" value="Yes" />
</div>

Comment: what version of fancybox? also, what is the idea to have an inline form with no fields? ... in that case, you should also show your javascript code for the functions `close_popup()` and `delete_account_2()` and any other that may populate the form if any